# Updating resource files for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, itunes

I've developed a generic iPhone app, intended for customization via a myapp.cfg file.  I've successfully deployed the app to my adhoc testers via iTunes.  My question is, how do I update their myapp.cfg file via iTunes.  In other words, if they edit the .cfg file on their Windows PC or Macbook, how do they get it into the apps bundle in the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to provide your own mechanism to download the config file into the application's Documents area; as app bundles are effectively sealed by the code signing process there's no way to modify the bundle post facto. As you have no interface to iTunes you need to provide your own mechanism - you might choose to do something like [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnifocus/) which uses Bonjour to discover the computer from which it retrieves its sync settings.

Looking at it another way; why use a config file at all? Other iPhone applications use a [settings bundle](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationSettings/ApplicationSettings.html) and the standard application preferences [as recommended by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/HandleTasks/HandleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH16-SW4), why do something different? There's always a chance that you'll confuse the user.